# How to remove the agent from Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-mods

I have been using a block coding program called "Tynker" for the Bedrock version of Minecraft. I was experimenting with the agent. But, for some odd reason, I can't remove it from my world! I tried the basic commands, such as `kill @e`, and even variants of such commands. He is invincible, too.

Comment: On Minecraft Education the agent is selected with @c, give it a try

Comment: @pinckerman /kill @c didnt do anything.

Comment: did you try `remove agent`? You create the agent using `create agent`, which is different from all other entities, so it makes sense that you cannot kill it like all other entities, either. See https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Agent

Comment: @Plagiatus I am using Minecraft Bedrock Edition, not Minecraft Education Edition.

Comment: you can't get the agent into your world in bedrock edition, unless you activated education edition for said world. Or at least you shouldn't be able to...

Comment: @Plagiatus I used tynker to put it in.

Comment: ah well... then can you use tynker to take it back out? Otherwise you might be stuck with it.